# How to line up text in a unordered list of images

Tags: html

I have an unordered list of items where each item is an image followed by some text. I would like the text to line up exactly, but due to the icons being slightly different sizes, the text of each is not aligned. See the JSFiddle below for an example. You can see the "O" of Option is further to the left than the "R" of RSS feed.

What is the easiest way of achieving this? Is there a way to do this WITHOUT changing the images?

This is my HTML:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a id="login" style="cursor:pointer;"><img src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/up.gif" /> Login</a></li>
  <li><a id="upload" style="cursor:pointer;"><img src="http://static.bbci.co.uk/id/0.23.4/img/bbcid_orb_signin_dark.png" /> Upload a file</a></li>
  <li><a id="option 3" style="cursor:pointer;"><img src="http://res2.windows.microsoft.com/resbox/en/windows%207/main/4f6cbd09-148c-4dd8-b1f2-48f232a2fd33_818.jpg"/>Option 3</a></li>
  <li><a id="rss" id="rss" ><img src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/up.gif" /> RSS Feed</a></li>
  <li><a id="about" style="cursor:pointer;"><img src="https://www.google.com/images/icons/product/googlemail-16.png" /> About</a></li>
</ul>
```

There is a JSFiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/9f1gxLv6/

Thanks,

Phil

Comment: Are you attached to this markup? You can achieve this better with a bit different structure.

Comment: I am not attached to the markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to space the icons and text evenly horizontally I recommend using the images as backgrounds instead of inline, then adding some padding:

```css
#login {
    background-image: url('http://www.w3schools.com/images/up.gif');
}
#upload {
    background-image: url('http://static.bbci.co.uk/id/0.23.4/img/bbcid_orb_signin_dark.png');
}
#option_3 {
    background-image: url('http://res2.windows.microsoft.com/resbox/en/windows%207/main/4f6cbd09-148c-4dd8-b1f2-48f232a2fd33_818.jpg');
}
#rss {
    background-image: url('http://www.w3schools.com/images/up.gif');
}
#about {
    background-image: url('https://www.google.com/images/icons/product/googlemail-16.png');
}
a {
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 2px 0 2px 30px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: left center;
}
```

```html
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a id="login" style="cursor:pointer;">Login</a>

    </li>
    <li><a id="upload" style="cursor:pointer;">Upload a file</a>

    </li>
    <li><a id="option_3" style="cursor:pointer;">Option 3</a>

    </li>
    <li><a id="rss" id="rss">RSS Feed</a>

    </li>
    <li><a id="about" style="cursor:pointer;">About</a>

    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I like it. I'm not sure I fully understand it - can any element in HTML have a background image? 

Are there any known issues with older browsers? (in particular IE 8 - sorry I don't have IE8 here, but need to support it! )

Comment: Gah! I think it's not supported in IE8!! ( http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts )

Comment: I think almost every element can have a background image. At least none come to mind that can't. And yes, it's extremely backwards compatible.

Comment: IE has background image support all the way back to IE4.

Comment: Am I reading this website wrong then? ( http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts )

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what that chart is trying to tell us, but you can see at the chart at the bottom of this MDN page (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image) that it's supported.

Comment: I think the canisue is referring to certain CSS3 properties which don't apply here.